# Java Generics: Generics not within bounds at initialization

Tags: java, generics

I am working with generics in Java™, and have found that I have a slight problem. I know Java™ uses [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html); however, I need to get the class of the generic at run-time. Therefore, I use a simple runaround to find the class of the generic, described [here](http://blog.xebia.com/acessing-generic-types-at-runtime-in-java/). The issue I am having is when I compile, `javac` spits out this:

```
C:\blah\Board.java:65: error: type argument T#1 is not within bounds of type-variable T#2
  this.boardManager = new NumberBoardManager<T>(c);
                                             ^
where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
  T#1 extends Comparable<? super T#1> declared in class Board
  T#2 extends Number,Comparable<? super T#2> declared in class NumberBoardManager
C:\blah\Board.java:65: error: constructor NumberBoardManager in class NumberBoardManager<T#2> cannot be applied to given types;
  this.boardManager = new NumberBoardManager<T>(c);
                      ^
required: Class<T#1>
found: Class<CAP#1>
reason: actual argument Class<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Class<T#1> by method invocation conversion
where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
  T#1 extends Comparable<? super T#1> declared in class Board
  T#2 extends Number,Comparable<? super T#2> declared in class NumberBoardManager
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
  CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
```

The first error makes sense, as the class I am in, `Board` has a generic that only extends `Comparable<? super T>`, while this specific constructor uses the fact that I want (but not necessarily have) a generic that also extends `Number`. I want to fix this issue by having the generic I use to create the `boardManager` to extend both `Number` and `Comparable<? super T>`, and to error out if the generic doesn't extend `Number`. But I don't know of any syntax which would help me at this point.

The second error is caused because I have already initialized `boardManager` with the generic `T`. But if we know `T` implements `Comparable<? super T>`, why does this error get thrown? I hope with the solving of the first issue, that the second issue is taken care of as well. Here is some code to provide context, and I am willing to provide more if you are still confused.

#### **Board.java**

```
public class Board<T extends Comparable<? super T>> extends Object implements Serializable
{
  private BoardManager<T> boardManager;

  public Board(int size)
  {
    Class<?> c = ((Class<?>)((ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
    if(c.isAssignableFrom(Number.class))
    {
      this.boardManager = new NumberBoardManager<T>(c); //this is the line
    }
  }
}
```

#### **NumberBoardManager.java**

```
public class NumberBoardManager<T extends Number & Comparable<? super T>> extends Object implements BoardManager<T>, Serializable
{
  private Class<T> c;

  public NumberBoardManager(Class<T> c)
  {
    this.c = c;
  }
}
```

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your code will not work at all; `getGenericSuperclass` is meaningless if you extend `Object`.  You can't hack around type erasure like that.

Comment: Why are you specifying that each class extends `Object`? Every object in Java is an `Object` so there is no need to explicitly state that

Comment: @smac89 I specified this so that you as the readers had context for what it extended. I wasn't sure if I could even get around type erasure as SLaks suggested. Also, this is the comments section of the question and does not help to better the answer to the question. If you were to look at my code, I even import the lang packages just to see where they come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to fix this issue by having the generic I use to create the boardManager to extend both Number and Comparable, and to error out if the generic doesn't extend Number.

You can't do that.

You can't have methods on a class that are only allowed with certain type parameterizations; the class must be able to fully function with any allowed type parameter.

You need to constrain the entire `Board` class to have `T` be `Number`.

The other error is because `Class<?>` isn't compatible with `Class<T>`.  `<?>` means that the type parameter might be *any* possible type; it might be something that violates `T`'s constraint.
You need to cast to `Class<T>`.

Comment: Thank you! I would like to also ask: is there a better way to do this then? I have another constructor which can take in a `BoardManager`, but it is cumbersome to write the class three times: `Board<Integer> b = new Board<Integer>(4, new NumberBoardManager<Integer>(Integer.class))`

Comment: You can't do this at all; due to type erasure, you can't tell what `T` is.

Comment: Are you on Java 7 or greater?  Will `new Board<>(4, new NumberBoardManager<>(Integer.class))` work?

Comment: I am on Java 7, and I hope so. But I wanted to evade diamond notation, as I am hoping to eventually have this code easily extendable.

Comment: @astrogeek14: If you don't want to constrain the type variable on the whole class but want something like a constructor that only works with certain `T`s, you can use a factory method (a static method that creates and returns an instance of the class, and the method is generic with its type variable constrained how you like). However, that still won't solve the problem that you can't get the class of `T` at runtime.